# Download File using JavasScript BUT file do not have extension like .doc .png etc

Tags: javascript

I have file which does not have any extension. When I open this file with .doc it opens. However, when I try to download it in Chrome, it fails with the error "no file". How can I download this file?

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', url);
element.setAttribute('download', "MyFile1");
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

href = "http://localhost:SomePortNumber/Files/Students/09576844-bd38-136d-a83a-fdf15bad524e_qwerty11"

[image]

Create docx file -> Edit the name basically removing the extension -> save.
Now this file is uploaded to server but when I download it starts and then fails "Failed - No File".

[image]

Comment: When you say: `but when I download it fails.` means that doesn't start to download the file at all?

Comment: Download starts and then I see "Failed - No File". As shown in the above attached screenshot. Please see original question, I have updated with screenshot.

Comment: This sounds like an error in the server side code that is generating the HTTP response with(out) the file in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set extension beside file name.
Like this.

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', url);
element.setAttribute('download', "MyFile1.txt");
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

if you still facing problem then this article will help you.

> https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server